# Skip or add where condition until i get a row count 1 as result

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I am looking for some CTE or query where i need to stop execute/ignore the where condition once i get a result of 1 record

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeTest
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,Name VARCHAR(100)
    ,City VARCHAR(100)
    ,Phone VARCHAR(100)
    ,ZipCode VARCHAR(20)
)


INSERT INTO EmployeeTest VALUES ('Venkat','Hyderabad','9849898401','500018')
INSERT INTO EmployeeTest VALUES ('Venkat','Hyderabad','9849898401','500019')
INSERT INTO EmployeeTest VALUES ('Venkat','Hyderabad','9849898402','500019')
INSERT INTO EmployeeTest VALUES ('Venkat','Secunderabad','9849898402','500019')
INSERT INTO EmployeeTest VALUES ('Name1','Secunderabad','9849898402','500019')

Ex: 1
--output is 1
select * from employeetest
where name = 'Venkat'
and city = 'hyderabad'
and phone='9849898401'
and zipcode='500018'
```

OUTPUT:
1   Venkat  Hyderabad   9849898401  500018

Ex 2:
results with zipcode 500020.

```
select * from employeetest
where name = 'Venkat'
and city = 'hyderabad'
and phone='9849898401'
and zipcode='500020'
```

OUTPUT:
output should be 1 record but we need to ignore the zipcode as we have no records with zipcode 500020.

```
We have two records but i need first as output
1   Venkat  Hyderabad   9849898401  500018
2   Venkat  Hyderabad   9849898401  500019
Final Output would be,
1   Venkat  Hyderabad   9849898401  500018
```

I think we can do it with CTE but unable to achieve it.

The objective is we need to apply each condition in where clause until we get a single record. If we get more records for condition one [name = 'Venkat'] we need to apply second [city='hyderabad'] and so on.....

Any ideas! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
DECLARE @city VARCHAR(100) = 'hyderabad'
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100) = 'Venkat'
DECLARE @phone VARCHAR(100) = '9849898401'
DECLARE @zipcode VARCHAR(100) = '500020'

SELECT TOP 1 ID, Name, City, Phone, ZipCode, t.matches
FROM EmployeeTest 
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT IIF(Name=@name, 1, 0) + IIF(City=@city, 1, 0) + 
          IIF(Phone=@phone, 1, 0) + IIF(ZipCode=@zipcode, 1, 0) AS matches) AS t
WHERE t.matches <> 0
ORDER BY t.matches DESC
```

The query returns a single record having the greatest number of matches.

Comment: I think you need to add `where t.matches <> 0` so it doesn't return anything if nothing matches.

Comment: @artm Good catch! I've edited my answer, thank you very much.

Comment: awesome Many thanks Giorgos and artm, the result is same as what i am looking for but not sure on how the CROSS APPLY works here.

Comment: @Giorgos, if i send below parameters i am getting result which matches both the values, is it possible to ignore the records which are not matched for first condition and apply the second condition [with out appending instead?]
DECLARE name VARCHAR(100) = 'Venkat'
DECLARE city VARCHAR(100) = 'Secunderabad'
DECLARE phone VARCHAR(100) = NULL
DECLARE zipcode VARCHAR(100) = NULL

Comment: @VenkataRatnamKallakuri Yes, this is possible, but my answer addresses the question posted. If you have a different question, then try writing a new post.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use `CTE`. You can use below query for only 1 record.

```
select top 1 * from employeetest
where name = 'Venkat'
```

This gives you only `one record with name of 'Venkat'`